# Azure Function: Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [DB6P189CA0021.EURP189.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I want to send email in Azure Function. I write down below code. ***It works properly in console app*** & I am able to send email using the credentials. But when I tested the same code in Azure Function it throws me below error.

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more errors occurred. f-HttpTriggerCSharp__-1774598883: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [DB6P189CA0021.EURP189.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

The code I used  -

```
 SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        string _sender = "--email--";
        string _password = "-password---";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_sender, _password);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Credentials = credentials;
        string recipient = "--test@outlook.com--";
            string subject="Temperature of device exceeds";
        string message="Temperature of device exceeds";
        try
        {
            var mail = new MailMessage(_sender.Trim(), recipient.Trim());
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.Body = message;
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Comment: any solution so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I use a queuetrigger and follow your code in my azure function(v1) and it works well.

> The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

This message indicates that the SMTP server configured in your Outgoing Mail Account is connecting to an SMTP client submission endpoint which cannot be used for direct send.

Configure your Exchange SMTP to direct send.

Configure the email notification In the `DS-Client > setup > configuration > notification` Selected `SMTP`, add the SMTP server settings and selected add the SMTP server settings
Server require authentication.

Add the office365 authenticated account information in the SMTP server authentication window.

Refer to the following Microsoft articles for more information:

[Fix issues with printers, scanners, and LOB applications that send email using Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fix-issues-with-printers-scanners-and-lob-applications-that-send-email-using-office-365-c75542a8-c792-42c0-a8c5-291df987512d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

[How to set up a multifunction device or application to send email using Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#DirectSendConfig)